Why can't I get the pdb file of the electron application even though I have configured includePdb: true
I have configured "includePdb" as true in "package.json" like this. However, after building with electron-builder, the corresponding PDB file is not found in the output.
"build": {
"includePdb": true
}
I want to know how to get the PDB file of the electron application?
